# How can I solve $x^4+x+1=0$ in $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

I know the equation $x^4+x+1=0$ has no real root, but how can I solve it in complex numbers?

Comment: Please include your attempts at the problem.

Comment: There is a formula for the roots but the result is not pretty.

Comment: I have some bad news: it does not appear that the [exact solutions](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4++%2B+x+%2B+1+%3D+0) will be easy to arrive at by hand at all. Would you include the context of the problem as well?

Answer (score 4):

It seems they are not going to have nice forms and the ones provided by Wolfram Alpha seem to use the explicit equation for the roots of an order 4 polynomials. One way is to get some more information about the roots is to get the inverse function, doing this I have produced a hypergeometric representation of one of the roots which in my opinion looks nicer, start with
$$
f(x) = x^4 + x + 1
$$
then perform a [series reversion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html) which gives
$$
f^{-1}(x) = (x-1)-(x-1)^4 + 4(x-1)^7 - 22(x-1)^{10} + 140(x-1)^{13} - \cdots
$$
checking the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C4%2C22%2C140%2C969&language=english&go=Search) we can see that this is
$$
f^{-1}(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{3n+1} \binom{4n}{n} (x-1)^{3n+1}
$$
Mathematica tells me that this is related to a hypergeometric function
$$
f^{-1}(x) = (x-1)\;_3F_2\left( \frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4};\frac{2}{3},\frac{4}{3};-\frac{256}{27} (x-1)^3 \right)
$$
using the property that $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$ then $f(f^{-1}(0))=0$ so $f^{-1}(0)$ is a root
$$
f^{-1}(0) = r_1 = -\;_3F_2\left( \frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4};\frac{2}{3},\frac{4}{3};\frac{256}{27} \right)\approx -0.727136 + 0.430014 i
$$
by symmetry the complex conjugate of $r_1$ is also a root. I'm not currently sure how to get any similar representation for the other two roots.

Comment: (+1) This is a good numerical approach. Notice that once you know that the roots are of the form $\alpha,\overline{\alpha},\beta,\overline{\beta}$ and you have an approximation for $\alpha$, you also have an approximation for $\beta$, since by Vieta's formulas we have $\beta+\overline{\beta}=-(\alpha+\overline{\alpha})$ and $\|\beta\|=\frac{1}{\|\alpha\|}$.

Comment: In particular the roots are close to $-0.727\pm 0.43 i$ and $0.727\pm 0.9341 i$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thank you for bringing Vieta's formulas to my attention, you are a fountain of knowledge!

Comment: How do you  get a complex value for a hypergeometric function with real parameters? Are we dealing with any sort of analytic continuation thing?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes, because the argument is greater than $1$ so the traditional series would run into problems, I think. I bypassed this by using a generating function which is only convergent for small $x$ and let Mathematica sort out the continuation.

Comment: Ok got it! +1 by the way for a totally different approach.

Answer (score 2):

A polynomial of 4th order can be written and a product of quadratics:$$x^4+x+1=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$$
Find out the $a,b,c,d$ coefficients, by identifying coefficients of different powers of $x$. The solution of your initial equation is the union of the individual solutions of the two quadratics.

Comment: I get $\,a^6-4a^2-1=0$. Then what?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not clear solving for $a,b,c,d$ is any easier.

Comment: $a^2$ has only one positive root and then $2b=a^2-\frac{1}{a}$. But it's difficult to get the root analytically.

Comment: Nevertheless, this method is still good enough to get approximate complex solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Take $z^4+z+1=0 \\z=x+iy$ 
$$\quad{(x+iy)^2=x^2-y^2+2ixy\\(x^2-y^2+2ixy)^2+(x+iy)+1=0\\(x^2-y^2)^2-4xy +4ixy(x^2-y^2)+x+iy+1=0\\\begin{cases}real-part=0\\image -part=0\end{cases}\\\begin{cases}(x^2-y^2)^2-4xy +x+1=0\\i(4xy(x^2-y^2)+y)=0\end{cases}}$$

Comment: I think you mean $z^4+ z+1 = 0$